# Conversion error .doc to .epub

Tags: epub

I uploaded .doc to smashworld, and got the warning while validating the .epub

ERROR   toc.ncx 15  43  Error while parsing file 'different playOrder values for navPoint/navTarget/pageTarget that refer to same target'.
ERROR   toc.ncx 15  265 Error while parsing file 'different playOrder values for navPoint/navTarget/pageTarget that refer to same target'.

And here is part of the codes.

Shan Hai Legend Vol.1, [Part 1of2]Midpoint

[image]

I have no idea..how it can be fixed. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know a ePub file is like an archive of files. It contains the textual files (usually .xhtml, .html), the stylesheet files (usually .css), the images used in the book and the configuration files. Your toc.ncx (The file that contains the index order and structure) has 2 or more items with the same playOrder or is corrupted.

The playOrder property specifies the actual position of the Chapter in the index.

If you use playOrder="1" with chapter 1 and playOrder="1" with chapter 2, the ePub reader doesn't know what to put first.

I suggest you to download Calibre, import your ePub, check for errors, and open the toc.ncx to see its structure.

You will get something like that:

```
<ncx xmlns="http://www.daisy.org/z3986/2005/ncx/" version="2005-1" xml:lang="it">
  <head>
    <meta content="...." name="...."/>
  </head>
  <docTitle>
    <text>Book Title</text>
  </docTitle>
  <navMap>
    <navPoint id="num_1" playOrder="1">
      <navLabel>
        <text>Chapter 1: some title</text>
      </navLabel>
      <content src="chapter-01.html"/>
    </navPoint>
    <navPoint id="num_2" playOrder="2">
      <navLabel>
        <text>Chapter 2: some title</text>
      </navLabel>
      <content src="chapter-02.html"/>
    </navPoint>
  </navMap>
</ncx>
```

Just check if every playOrder is incremented by 1 for each navpoint.
If you find the error, manually insert the correct values, save and export the eBook.

If you don't know how to fix it, post here the toc file and we will try to understand the mistake :)

Comment: I forgot to say that the mistake could be as well a src="" problem, in which two different play orders are applied to the same file using two different navpoints.